# I have added new columns in table and when I getting this error

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to System.DateTime;

I have added below highlighted columns in the existing table:

[image]

and when I am getting data, I have got the above exception:

```
var tempData = _context.Finance.Where(x => x.id == id)
```

Can anyone please guide, I am using Entity Framework Core. I have the same datatime in model also.

Entity model:

```
public class Finance
{
        [Key] 
        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
        public int created_by { get; set; }
        public DateTime delivered_date { get; set; }
        public int call_origin { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
        public int sheet_num { get; set; }
        public string bank_name { get; set; }
        public float bank_deposit_amount { get; set; }
        public string department_to_assign { get; set; }
        public int receiving_type { get; set; }
        public float adjustment_amount { get; set; }
        public DateTime adjustment_date { get; set; }
        public int adjustment_type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your entity model?

Comment: Model added in the question, please have a look.

Comment: `receiving_type` is a string in the database, an int in your code.  Did you run a scaffold?

Comment: updated the receiving_type, but same issue. @LarsTech

Comment: No I haven't scaffold?

Comment: Do you have migrations? Did you run add-migration? mayble your model builder is incomplete or have invalid mappings

Comment: You can try add manualy type for each of columns:
[Column("adjustment_date", Order = 9, TypeName = "datetime")]

Comment: I was only pointing out the first difference I saw.  You have other fields that are wrong, too.  Avoid doing this by hand.  Use a tool like [scaffold_dbcontext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell), etc.

Comment: `adjustment_type` has wrong type too

Comment: I think a `?` is missing for all columns that allow NULL values, like `public int? created_by { get; set; }`, see: [Nullable value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)  (This is beside the already mentioned other problems)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your the model from database.

I faced a similar problem and had to remove the table and re-add to the model.